# Automatic url linking

Tags: url, weblinks

I want that my links for example http://mysite.com get automatically converted to a hyperlink when i paste it in the editor. How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TinyMCE (the default editor) and also JCE Editor and probably most editors, a pasted url is automatically changed to a hyperlink if you press the space bar or the return key immediately after the link.

This is convenient but you may still want to edit the hyperlink to add title text for better SEO.